# Changing of c++ compiler in vs code when ever I am trying to create a new folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

So, whenever I create a new folder in vs code, the default compiler comes out to be gcc-11 but I want it to be clang.

c_cpp_properites.json file when I am trying to create a cpp file in a new folder:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/gcc-11",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intellisenseMode": "macos-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I have to replace my .json file code over and over again with the given code.

new c_cpp_properties.json file:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "/usr/local/include",
            "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11",
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/x86_64-apple-darwin21"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "macFrameworkPath": [],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang++",
        "cStandard": "gnu17",
        "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
        "intellisenseMode": "macos-clang-x64"
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

So I want that whenever I create a new folder the vs code's default c_cpp_properties should be the second one, not the first one. Can anyone help me out to do so?

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly. See the meta post [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812).

Comment: If you build with cmake then the cmake plugin will configure vscode for you and you don't need to create `c_cpp_properties.json`